# Why is my defined range not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript

My range does not seem to be working. E.g. if I input the smallest number to be 10, and the biggest number to be 20, it would not give me within the range. Any idea how to fix this?

```js
var randomNo;

function playFunction() {
  message1 = document.getElementById("wrongInput");
  message1.innerHTML = "";
  message2 = document.getElementById("wrongInput2");
  message2.innerHTML = "";
  x = document.getElementById("input").value;
  x2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;

  try {
    if (x == "")
      throw "empty";

    if (isNaN(x))
      throw "not a number";
  } catch (err) {
    message1.innerHTML = "Input is " + err;
    message1.style.color = "red";
    x = Number(x);

  }

  try {
    if (x2 == "")
      throw "empty";

    if (isNaN(x2))
      throw "not a number";
    x2 = Number(x2);
  } catch (err) {
    message2.innerHTML = "Input is " + err;
    message2.style.color = "red";
    x2 = Number(x2);
  }

  try {
    if (Number(x) > Number(x2))
      throw "must be higher than the lowest number";
  } catch (err) {
    message2.innerHTML = "The input " + err;

  }

  var min = document.getElementById("input").value;
  console.log(min);
  var max = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  console.log(max);
  randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1))
  console.log(randomNo);

}
```

```html
<html>
Enter a smaller number<br>
<input id="input" type="text">
<span id="wrongInput"></span><br> Enter a larger number<br>
<input id="input2" type="text">
<span id="wrongInput2"></span><br>
<button type="button" onclick="playFunction()">Play button</button>
<br>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote the random part wrong. In `Math.random() * (max - min + 1)` you actually get the random number (between 0 and 1) and multiply it by the number that comes out of the parenthesis and that would be the new max value of the overall number, but in order to change the min value you'll have to increment this overall number you can do it like so:

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

and with a bit of improvement in your code:

```js
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
}

function playFunction() {
  const message1 = document.getElementById("wrongInput");
  const message2 = document.getElementById("wrongInput2");
  const min = Number(document.getElementById("input").value);
  const max = Number(document.getElementById("input2").value);
  let randomNo;
  
  function init() {
    message2.innerHTML = "";
    message1.innerHTML = "";
  }

  function validateInput(displayErrorElement, value) {
    let message;
    
    if (value == "")
      message =  "empty";
    else if (isNaN(value))
      message = "not a number";
      
    if(message) {
      displayErrorElement.innerHTML = "Input is " + message;
      displayErrorElement.style.color = "red";
      
      return false;
    }
    
    return true;
  }
  
  function validateRange(displayErrorElement, min, max) {
    if (min > max) {
      displayErrorElement.innerHTML = "The input must be higher than the lowest number";
      
      return false;
    }
    
    return true;
  }
  
  init();
  if(!validateInput(message1, min)) return false;
  if(!validateInput(message2, max)) return false;
  if(!validateRange(message2, min, max)) return false;
  
  console.log(min);
  console.log(max);
  randomNo = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(min, max));
  console.log(randomNo);

}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="input">Enter a smaller number<label>
<input id="input" type="text">
<div id="wrongInput"></div>
<label for="input2">Enter a larger number</label>
<input id="input2" type="text">
<div id="wrongInput2"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="playFunction()">Play button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me to tidy up my codes, however I'm wondering what was wrong with my random method?

Comment: I added an explanation (I forgot about that sorry. let me know if it's clear enough

Comment: oh sorry and can i ask, you put getRandomArbitary(min, max) and then at the var randomNo = getRandomArbitary(max,min) does the position of min & max matter?

Comment: yea sorry my bad. it matters